# Install Linux to in-use hard drive from within Windows XP

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot

I have a vintage desktop PC that I want to repurpose as a simple Linux-based appliance. It runs Windows XP (Home) and none of its internal drives (including floppy!) are functional, except for the (IDE) OS HDD. The BIOS lists a number of USB boot options, but I've had no success with those either, whether with a liveCD in a USB optical drive or a liveUSB thumbdrive. There is also a PXE boot option but (a) that seems very complex to setup a server for and (b) I don't know that I'd trust that to work on this box either.

There are two unneeded empty partitions on the HDD apart from the C:\ partition, so it'd be possible to install another OS perhaps from an image, but I'm uncertain how I'd then be able to boot it.

I have had a glimmer of hope in using an app called Grub2Win, which hooks into XP's boot.ini menu and loads GRUB2. So I have a GRUB shell available, but have not yet hit upon how I can use it to boot anything other than the default XP option. (When I attempt to add an additional menu item within its setup GUI, it crashes.)

The ideal scenario would be to load something that will reside entirely in memory when booted, and has an option to full-install to HDD (and is sufficiently legacy-tolerant that I can be confident it will actually boot once installed!).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)? I don't know how well supported it is now, but it'll allow you to use a Windows based installer to a file on your current partitions.

Comment: Hi Jonno, it's an interesting option but at first glance it sounds like virtualisation - is that right? Not clear how I'd get from this to a bare-metal Linux install.

Comment: It does not rely on virtualisation, no. See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(software)) for more information, particularly the limitations part. It's essentially an installation of Ubuntu within a file on an NTFS partition, with another file used for SWAP, but displayed to Linux as if they were dedicated partitions. If you're happy with it, the installation can then be transferred to actual partitions.

Comment: OK I see. This might have been a viable solution but it looks to be unsupported now; I found a 9.04 version but of course it could not download the needed ISO to install Ubuntu from any mirror.

Answer (score 0):

[Jonno](https://superuser.com/users/536125/jonno) deserves some props here, as the "See also" section in the wiki link he posted above was the route to my solution.

The almost childishly simple solution was the Debian Installer, found at

http://goodbye-microsoft.com/

Download the linked Windows executable from this page, it installs itself onto the C: drive and adds its entry to BOOT.INI. Reboot, choose that added entry from the menu on boot, and proceed to install Debian (Jessie, in this instance) directly onto the entirety of the HDD (or whatever partitioning-scheme suits; the Windows install can be -- and normally is -- preserved).

One nervy moment came when installing GRUB to the MBR, as the installer raised a warning that GRUB was "configured to boot in EFI configuration" but as I had already wiped out the Windows partition by then, and there was already no going back, I just clicked through on the default and all was fine.

There is one "gotcha": it ignored the default user I'd defined within the initial Windows executable.  On the second reboot (after installation), I was left with a login prompt with no way of logging in.  (This may be because I eschewed installing any part of the "Debian desktop system" in the installer, wanting only a server install.)

Solution to that issue:

1. When the GRUB menu appears, select "Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux" and, from the sub-menu, the second option that ends "(recovery mode)".
2. Once you get a prompt, type `passwd` and follow the prompts to set a root password.
3. From there you can reboot, login as root and create more users as needed using `useradd` or `adduser` (I prefer the latter).